# Javascript: how to open a url in Safari browser where as the application is running in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, java, ios

I have a web application which is build to run on mobile devices with any browser. but there are two links which I want to open in specific browser which is say Safari.

Comment: What if the user doesn't have Safari?

Comment: this is for iphone, I am checking the user agent and probability for having safari there is 99%

Comment: Do you mind me asking why you would want something to run in a specific browser?

Comment: The reason is i want to run my web applications as native iphone apps by using the utility of add to home screen.. but in some browsers the add to home screen doesn't seem visible so I want when user comes on download page it automatic redirect user to safari so they can use the navigation and add to home screen combination to make a native app short cut. This is my  all motive.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you need - [application:openURL:options:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW2)

I've only glanced at the doc but it seems you can choose a particular app to handle a URL.